# no such file exception even though the path is correct in spring framwork

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing an API with spring boot.
Here is the function where the error occurs:

```
@GetMapping(path="/image/{fileName}",produces= MimeTypeUtils.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] getServerImage(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException{
    
    System.out.println(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Bureau/"+fileName)); //to see if the path is correct, it is correct.
    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Bureau/"+fileName));
    
}
```

I printed the path to see if it's correct here :

C:\Users\ENVY\Bureau\server1.png

I thought that it was a privilege problem, I run STS(spring tool suite) as admin and the problem persists.

```
2022-03-16 10:09:11.634 ERROR 5108 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\ENVY\Bureau\server1.png
    at
java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
~[na:na]    at
java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
~[na:na]    at
java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
~[na:na]    at
java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:236)
~[na:na]    at
java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
~[na:na]    at
java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3288) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: How have you verified that the "path is correct"? What happens if you paste the path into the windows run dialog?

Comment: Admins don't have access to user directories by default.